# Should I spawn one thread per disk writing operation?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am making a crawler to download some images extensively and I want to speed up by using thread (I'm new to multithreading). I am not sure about the inner mechanism behind disk writing operation. Can I write different files to disk simultaneously using thread? (does the writing get scheduled automatically?) Or should I make a lock for disk access for each thread to take turns and write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point. Disk write operations aren't blocking anyway, so there's no point in creating many threads just to perform them.

Comment: Does that mean I only need to use thread for downloading tasks? I read that there is only one needle per HDD and it has to switch back and forth to write multiple files, or should I say, it does it sequentially

Comment: @GiaPhatHa It depends what else the downloading tasks do, but you definitely don't need multiple threads for the disk writing portion. What's the limiting factor in your downloading operation? If it's the network, then more threads won't help.